# How to filtering the data in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to filtering the dataset in R shiny

Here is the sample UI that I make:
[image: Basic UI outline]

As you can see, there is x and y axis min and max on the bottom to show the area that I am selected.
I want to design a little operation call "Filtering data" which the desired output will be:
Filtering out the x, y coordination are not inside the brushed area

Here is the code:
ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Select Each Individual to graph"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(uiOutput("directories"),
                 uiOutput("csv_files"),
                 actionButton('load_csv', 'Give me Plot and data!'),
                 actionButton('DeleteSelectedData', 'Delete Data! '),
                 actionButton("save", "Save")
                 ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("ori_plot",
                                             brush = "plot_brush",
                                             width = "800px", 
                                             height = "400px")),
        tabPanel("Selected Area Data", dataTableOutput("area")),
        tabPanel("Data before/after Deleted Operation", dataTableOutput("new_data"))
        )
      )
    ),
  #verbatimTextOutput("debug")
  verbatimTextOutput("info"),
  verbatimTextOutput("unique")
  )
)
```

Server.R

```
#
# This is the server logic of a Shiny web application. You can run the
# application by clicking 'Run App' above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
library(tools)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Only need to manual get the base directory because it is in the different 
  #location
  R_file_location <- "D:/R_Codes/HQA-26954/ux-analysis-touchmonitor"
  task_path <- "1.light_palm_swiping/log_data/shiny"
  source(paste0(R_file_location, "/", "touch_monitor_config.R"))
  study_config <- touch_monitor_config(readLines(paste0(R_file_location,"/", "touch_monitor_config_file_path.txt")))
  
  files_df <- study_config[["files"]]
  
  main_dir <- as.character(files_df)
  analysis_dir <- paste(main_dir, "_analysis", sep = "/")
  data_dir <- paste0(analysis_dir, '/', task_path)
  all_dirs <- list.dirs(data_dir,
                        recursive = FALSE,
                        full.names = FALSE)
  
  output$directories <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId  = "directories",
                label = 'Select directory',
                choices = all_dirs)
  })
  
  output$csv_files <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId  = "csv_files",
                label = 'Select csv',
                choices = list.files(paste0(data_dir, "/", input$directories)))
  })

  re_palm_swiping <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$load_csv, {
    re_palm_swiping$data <- read.csv(paste0(data_dir, "/", input$directories, "/", input$csv_files))
    })
  
  #Generating the plot based on data selected 
  output$ori_plot <- renderPlot({
    #Need to use req() because initial data is null, to avoid warning
    req(re_palm_swiping$data)
    ggplot(re_palm_swiping$data, aes(x, y)) +
      geom_point(aes(color = factor(finger_index))) +
      labs(title = "finger contacts", color = "finger") +
      scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2")
    })
  
  #Output the Data Table from brushed area
  output$area <- renderDataTable({
    req(re_palm_swiping$data)
    # With base graphics, need to tell it what the x and y variables are.
    #Here is the exception, because we use ggplot2 no need to give xvar or yvar
    brushedPoints(re_palm_swiping$data, input$plot_brush)
  })
  
  #Get the delete button action 
  observeEvent(input$DeleteSelectedData, {
    Var1 <- brushedPoints(re_palm_swiping$data, input$plot_brush)
    x_cords_min <- function(e) {
      x_min <- e$xmin
    }
    x_cords_max <- function(e) {
      x_max <- e$xmax
    }
    y_cords_min <- function(e) {
      y_min <- e$ymin
    }
    y_cords_max <- function(e) {
      y_max <- e$ymax
    }
    x_cords_min <- x_cords_min(input$plot_brush)
    x_cords_max <- x_cords_max(input$plot_brush)
    y_cords_min <- y_cords_min(input$plot_brush)
    y_cords_max <- y_cords_max(input$plot_brush)
    
    test <- Var1[Var1$x <= 0,]
    
  })
  
  #Will change the data before or after delete button click
  output$new_data <- renderDataTable({
    test
  })
  
  #Will change the data before or after delete button click
  output$new_data <- renderDataTable({
    req(re_palm_swiping$data)
    re_palm_swiping$data
  })
  
  #Get the save button action
  observeEvent(input$save, {
    update_path <- paste0(data_dir, "/", "updated_csv")
    if (!dir.exists(update_path))
      dir.create(update_path)
    write.csv(re_palm_swiping$data, 
              paste(update_path,paste0(file_path_sans_ext(input$csv_files),"_updated.csv"),sep = "/"))
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        title = "File Save Completed",
        paste("You successfully save the file",
              file_path_sans_ext(input$csv_files),"_updated.csv to",
              paste(update_path,paste0(input$csv_files, "_updated.csv"),sep = "/")),
      size = "l",
      easyClose = TRUE
      ))
    })

  output$info <- renderText({
    x_y_cords_range <- function(e) {
      if(is.null(e)) return("NULL\n")
      paste0("xmin=", round(e$xmin), " xmax=", round(e$xmax), 
             " ymin=", round(e$ymin), " ymax=", round(e$ymax))
    }
    
    paste0("brush: ", x_y_cords_range(input$plot_brush))
    })

  # output$unique <- renderText({
  #   paste0("unique cords: ", test)
  # })
  
})
```

Here is the code that I get for the x y min and max:

```
  #Get the delete button action 
  observeEvent(input$DeleteSelectedData, {
    Var1 <- brushedPoints(re_palm_swiping$data, input$plot_brush)
    x_cords_min <- function(e) {
      x_min <- e$xmin
    }
    x_cords_max <- function(e) {
      x_max <- e$xmax
    }
    y_cords_min <- function(e) {
      y_min <- e$ymin
    }
    y_cords_max <- function(e) {
      y_max <- e$ymax
    }
    x_cords_min <- x_cords_min(input$plot_brush)
    x_cords_max <- x_cords_max(input$plot_brush)
    y_cords_min <- y_cords_min(input$plot_brush)
    y_cords_max <- y_cords_max(input$plot_brush)
    
    test <- Var1[Var1$x <= 0,]
    
  })
```

test <- Var1[Var1$x <= 0,]
In this code I was trying to find the x y that is in the area that I define:

```
    x_cords_min <- x_cords_min(input$plot_brush)
    x_cords_max <- x_cords_max(input$plot_brush)
    y_cords_min <- y_cords_min(input$plot_brush)
    y_cords_max <- y_cords_max(input$plot_brush)
```

However, I have tried:

```
test <- Var1[Var1$x <= 0,] or     
test <- Var1[Var1$x >= x_cords_min && Var1$x <= x_cords_max &&
                   Var1$y >= y_cords_min && Var1$y <= y_cords_max]
```

Updated: Here is the datasets:
[image: DataSet]
Nothing seems to work, Can I have any tips?
Thanks!

Comment: Your code is not reproducible since we don't have access to your data, nor your `touch_monitor_config.R` (and possibly more).  That said, i think the simplest solution would not be to filter the data but to use `coord_cartesian()` to "zoom" the graph: `... + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(x_cords_min, x_cords_max), ylim=c(y_cords_min, y_cords_max))`.

Comment: Sorry, but the coord_cartesian is belong to ggplot2 right? So I have to get the ggplot2 graph and use the coord_cartesian() function. If I am not mistaken

Comment: Correct.  It's part of the ggplot2 package.

Comment: In my server.R. Do I have to use the renderplot to show the graph? I assume I have to show the ggplot graph output instead of showing the data. Is there anyway I can delete the data not in brushed area? Or it is not going to work?

Answer (score 0):

Even with your latest screenshots, you are expecting us to transcribe your data by hand and then modify your code to handle whatever format we have decided to create.  That's not going to happen.  Ever.  Help yourself by helping us to help you.  Please read and follow the advice on creating a minimal reproducible example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  The words *minimal* and *reproducible* are equally important.

These are untested ideas as you have not provided us with what we need to test our solutions.

Ok.  Rant over.

My preferred way of doing this, as I suggested in my comment, is to do the following:

```
  output$ori_plot <- renderPlot({
    #Need to use req() because initial data is null, to avoid warning
    req(re_palm_swiping$data)
    ggplot(re_palm_swiping$data, aes(x, y)) +
      geom_point(aes(color = factor(finger_index))) +
      labs(title = "finger contacts", color = "finger") +
      scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") + 
      coord_cartesian(
        xlim=c(x_cords_min(input$plot_brush), x_cords_max(input$plot_brush)), 
        ylim=c(y_cords_min(input$plot_brush), y_cords_max(input$plot_brush))
     )
    })
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that any interpolation, model fitting or similar that you might do will still use the entire dataset.  If you filter the dataset, or apply limits to the graph's axes, this will not happen and the results may be unpredictable and the problems difficult to detect.  That doesn't appear to be an issue here, but it's still good practice.

If you really must filter your data and leave the graph code untouched, I would create a filtered copy of your original dataset and make the corresponding change to your `renderPlot`.  So, something like this:

```
observeEvent(input$plot_brush, {
  re_palm_swiping$filtered_data <- re_palm_swiping$data %>%
    filter(
      x >= x_cords_min(input$plot_brush) & x <= x_cords_max(input$plot_brush),
      y >= y_cords_min(input$plot_brush) & y <= y_cords_max(input$plot_brush)
    )
})

  output$ori_plot <- renderPlot({
    #Need to use req() because initial data is null, to avoid warning
    req(re_palm_swiping$filtered_data)
    ggplot(re_palm_swiping$filtered_data, aes(x, y)) +
      geom_point(aes(color = factor(finger_index))) +
      labs(title = "finger contacts", color = "finger") +
      scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2")
    })
```

Also, note that `file.path()` is a more robust option than `paste0()` when constructing file paths.  It's both more compact and independent of operating system.

Comment: sorry, I was not mean to just post the last excel file, and not doing the suggestion you provided, I have tried the code. but I don't know how to post it here. Do I use the edit button?

Comment: In the first, I use your solution to 'output$ori_plot' but I was not able to produce the graph. because I think I am not define the "x_cords_min(input$plot_brush)" in the function. Do I just move the code to 'output$ori_plot'? another question is that when I press the button, there is no brushed area, the code the graph will not be shown
Thanks for you help..